# image processing filter with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image-processing

If you look at Google Street View image, the image is radially distorted from the center towards the edges which gives a more realistic impression.

I want to achieve a similar effect using JavaScript.

So is there any image processing script/library/algorithm to provide this specific effect?

Comment: This looks pretty good - http://code.google.com/p/jspanoviewer/

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing off the shelf that I know of.  There are a bunch of ways you can handle this but none of them are very straight-forward:

In order of effort / realistically doing this:

- using pure CSS or JS, stretch the sides of the image starting from the center.  As an example, leave the middle 10% alone.  Stretch the next 9% to 10% width.  The next 8% to 10% width, then 7% to 10%, etc...  If using JS, use canvas, if using CSS you need tons of DIVS with offset background positions (google "CSS Coke Can" for the basic premise)
- Using something like Three.js, make a 3D environment and simply place the image as a background -- you'll get free distortion in WebGL.
- Using CSS3, break the image into a bunch of slices and lay them around a "camera" in cylindrical view.  You'll get edge distortion for "free" but only in modern browsers (i've done this, it works great).